# Selecting rows with timestamps set to the future

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of adverts. These adverts have `start` and `end` columns, which are both of the `DATETIME` type.

I need to select ones that are going to start in the next 24 hours, and, separately, ones that are going to end in the next 24 hours. I wrote the query `select * from slides where enabled = 1 and start <= NOW() + interval 24 hour`, which seemed to work at first.

The problem is, it also selects rows from a long time ago. I need it just to select ones starting between now and 24 hours from now.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use a UNION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, use two comparisons:

```
select s.*
from slides s
where s.enabled = 1 and
      s.start <= NOW() + interval 24 hour and
      s.start >= NOW();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in oracle you can modify it according the DB you are using

```
select * from slides where enabled = 1 and start between sysdate and sysdate+1
```

Here sysdate returns current date and time, adding 1 to it returns date and time 24 hours from now.

Answer (score 1):

I have a SQL Server background, but did a little research into the particularities of MySQL.

> I need to select ones that are going to start in the next 24 hours

```
/*This will provide you all that start in next 24 hours*/
SELECT S.* FROM Slides S WHERE S.Enabled = 1 AND S.Start <= NOW() + interval 24 hour AND
  S.Start >= NOW();
```

> and, separately, ones that are going to end in the next 24 hours

```
        /* This will separately select the ones that are going to end in the next 24 */
    hours.
UNION 
        SELECT S.* FROM Slides S WHERE S.Enabled = 1 AND S.END <= NOW() + interval 24 hour AND
  S.End>= NOW();
```

Run the two code blocks together as a single statement.  You will end up with a single result set that is comprised of two separate results from two differing statements.